# iOS Safari panning/touchmove event stuck on one axis

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events

Set up:

Inside a web app, I have a large table positioned inside a div, that sits inside another div. The outside div has absolute positioning on all sides, so often the table will not fit. The inner div has touch events registered on it (`touchstart` and `touchmove`), along with `overflow: auto`.

The problem:

Sometimes, when panning starts close to either the vertical or the horizontal axis, it gets stuck to the axis, and there is no way to change it once it started (i.e. we get horizontal/vertical scrolling only, no diagonal movement). Is there a way of preventing this 'axis lock', or, at the very least, detecting that this has happened?